# How to display glyphicon/font-awesome in sap.ui.core.Icon?

Tags: font-awesome, sapui5, glyphicons

As the collection of icons is pretty limited in SAPUI5/OpenUI5 I would like to display glyphicons and / or font-awesome icons in a sap.ui.core.Icon.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inorder to use an external icon within an existing control, you could use the sap.ui.core.IconPool control. The control provides a addIcon method for adding an Icon.

1. List item

   Declare the font-face tag in your CSS

   ```
   font-face {
     font-family: 'My-Icons'; 
     src: url('_PATH_TO_EOT_FILE_');
     src: url('_PATH_TO_EOT_FILE_?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /*?#iefix is required to be added to the end of the path of eot file here*/
        url('_PATH_TO_TTF_FILE_') format('truetype');
     font-weight: normal;
     font-style: normal;
   };
   ```

   Incase if you are using font-awesome, you could include the font-awesome styleshet in you manifest. The stylesheet will be included in the font-face declarations among other things, somewhat like this:

   ```
   @font-face {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0');
    src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.7.0') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.7.0') format('woff'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.7.0') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.7.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
   }
   ```
2. Call [sap.ui.core.IconPool.addIcon](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.IconPool.html#.addIcon) to add you Icon. You could declare
   this in you Component.js

   ```
   sap.ui.define([
     "sap/ui/core/UIComponent",
     "sap/ui/core/IconPool"],
    function(UIComponent, IconPool){
     "use strict";
    return UIComponent.extend("com.sap.app.Component",{
    metadata : {
       manifest: "json"
    },
    init : function(){
       //call the init function of the parent
       UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);
       //Init Router
       this.getRouter().initialize();

       IconPool.addIcon("battery", "fa", {
           fontFamily : "FontAwesome",
           content : "f241" 
       });
     }
    }); 
   });
   ```
3. You can now use this Icon in you control

   ```
   <mvc:View controllerName="com.sap.app.controller.App" 
     xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" 
     xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" 
     xmlns="sap.m">
     <core:Icon src="sap-icon://fa/battery" color="#031E48" ></core:Icon>
     <Button icon="sap-icon://fa/battery" press="onPress"></Button>
   </mvc:View>
   ```

You can also refer to the documentation here : https://help.sap.com/saphelp_uiaddon10/helpdata/en/21/ea0ea94614480d9a910b2e93431291/content.htm

Answer (score 3):

**Disclaimer**: shameless self-promotion.

For Font Awesome (and free version only), I've made a plugin just for this purpose: [ui5-fontawesome](https://github.com/zypA13510/ui5-fontawesome).

Internally, the plugin calls [`IconPool.registerFont()`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.IconPool/methods/sap.ui.core.IconPool.registerFont) for you, or [`IconPool.addIcon()`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.IconPool/methods/sap.ui.core.IconPool.addIcon) if on an older UI5 version where `IconPool.registerFont()` is not available.

Now all you have to do is to include the plugin in your html, and you can start using the icons by calling their icon names directly (e.g. `<core:Icon src="sap-icon://fa-brands/font-awesome"/>`)

```js
sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function() {
  sap.ui.define([
    'sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller', 'sap/ui/core/mvc/XMLView'
  ], function(Controller, XMLView) {
    XMLView.create({
      controller: new(Controller.extend('ui5.demo.controller', {}))('ui5.demo.controller'),
      definition: jQuery('#view').html(),
    }).then(function(oView) {
      oView.placeAt('content');
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<body class="sapUiBody" id="content">
  <script
    id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
    src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
    data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize"
    data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
    data-sap-ui-compatversion="edge"
    data-sap-ui-preload="async"
    data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{
      "ui5.demo": "./"
    }'>
  </script>
  <script id="view" type="text/xml">
    <mvc:View
      controllerName="ui5.demo.controller"
      xmlns="sap.m"
      xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
      xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
      displayBlock="true">
      <Shell>
        <App>
          <Page title="UI5-FontAwesome test">
            <core:Icon src="sap-icon://fa-brands/font-awesome" size="2.5rem" color="#339AF0" class="sapUiTinyMargin"/>
          </Page>
        </App>
      </Shell>
    </mvc:View>
  </script>
  <script
    src="https://unpkg.com/ui5-fontawesome@^1/js/ui5-fontawesome.min.js"
    id="ui5-fontawesome"
    data-resourceroot="https://unpkg.com/ui5-fontawesome@^1/">
  </script>
</body>
```