# FontAwesome icon usage issue in SAPUI5?

Tags: sapui5

I would like to use FontAwesome icons in my UI5 project. But I can't use the icons whatever I did. I don't know where I'm doing mistake. I'm getting this error **"The font configuration for collection 'fontawesome-regular' is not registered"**
Here is my codes;
I'm using a json file which is contains font icon datas.

```
oModel.loadData("/resources/datasets/fontawesome.json");
        oModel.attachRequestCompleted(function () {
            var fontAwesomeIcons = oModel.getProperty("/FontAwesomeIcons");
            fontAwesomeIcons.map(function (item, index) {
                sap.ui.core.IconPool.addIcon(item.id, "fontawesome-regular", {
                    fontFamily: "fa-regular",
                    text: item.name,
                    content: item.unicode
                });
            })
        });
```

Additionally I've a css file which contains a @font-face definition. Here is the image link [font-face image](https://ibb.co/TmVw2zD) Please take a look the image that shows the font-face
What should I do be able to solve this issue ?

Comment: Would this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43062459/how-to-display-glyphicon-font-awesome-in-sap-ui-core-icon

Comment: Thank you @Jorg. I've tried that method. But I'm still getting "fontawesome-regular" is not registered" error. Do I need to use registerFont method ?

Comment: I've never tried it, but if my error said "please register font" and I found a method that says "register font" I'd be inclined to give that shot :P

Comment: I've been researching a method about the registerFont.. but there isn't so much thing.. very restricted :) I hope I can find useful thing

Comment: I'm using a loop function.. here is the code if (response.length > 0) {
     response.map(function (icon) {
      if (icon.unicode) {
       sap.ui.core.IconPool.addIcon(icon.name, "normal", "normal", icon.unicode);
      }
     })
    } . IconPool.addIcon method throws an error called not registered. But If I add the icons row by row, it works properly. Wouldn't being used addIcon method in a loop function ?

Answer (score 3):

First, you should import eot, svg, ttf, woff, and woff2 files into your project. In my test project I created a special folder for this font and it looks like this:

[image: font folder structure]

Also I created a font.css file with this content (taken from Font Awesome **regular.css** file):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'fa-regular';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url("fa-regular-400.eot");
    src: url("fa-regular-400.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), 
        url("fa-regular-400.woff2") format("woff2"), 
        url("fa-regular-400.woff") format("woff"), 
        url("fa-regular-400.ttf") format("truetype"), 
        url("fa-regular-400.svg#fontawesome") format("svg");
}
```

Note that url do not have any prefixes as they reference files in the same folder.
Then I added  **fa-regular.json** file with all registered icons from the font. **json** file name must be the same as the font face name entered in the css file. My file has a single icon:

```
{
    "smile-wink": "f4da"
}
```

I took the icon code from **svg** file:
[image: SVG file]

Then I registered css file in my **manifest.json** file:
[image]

Then I added font registration code into my Component.js code:

```
    sap.ui.core.IconPool.registerFont({
        collectionName: "font-awesome-icons",
        fontFamily: "fa-regular",
        fontURI: "font-awesome",
        lazy: false
    });
```

Here **collectionName** can be arbitrary name of your choice, you use it for referencing icons in your XML views.
**fontFamily** must be the same as declared in css file.
**fontUri** must lead to the folder where your fonts reside. In my case it is folder f**ont-awesome**.

Finally, I used new icon in my XML view:
[image: XML view]

And this is how it looks in the browser:

[image]